# zsh: command not found: ansible after pip installing

Tags: macos, ansible

I've installed ansible on my Mac using pip as advised by ansible's documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-macos

However when I try to run ansible I get the following:
`zsh: command not found: ansible`

I've never had this problem when installing ansible before.

pip-installing again tells me it's already installed under site packages:
`Requirement already satisfied: ansible in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.9.11)`

And my python installation in ~/.zshrc points to:

```
# Add user python 3.7 to path
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Might be obvious to some but I can't figure out why this simple installation isn't working..

Comment: Which command did you use to install Ansible? `pip install --user ansible`? `sudo pip install ansible`?

Comment: I installed using the recommended `pip install --user ansible`

Comment: You may want to check `$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin` and see if it wrote the shell scripts there; I can't tell based on the output what `.` represents in that case; you may also want to try `pip uninstall -y ansible && pip install --user -v -v -v ansible` and see exactly what it does

Comment: @mdaniel thanks - ansible does exist in that Python/3.8/bin folder, so I've just created an alias for it in my .zshrc file. I've not had to do this before. Is there any drawbacks in having ansible setup like this?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, although if that `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` is because python was installed via Homebrew, are you aware that you can `brew install ansible` and then just put `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH?

Comment: @mdaniel Much appreciated - I did just pip uninstall, removed the lines in my .zshrc, and re-installed using brew, and now ansible works just fine :)
Previously I couldn't get ansible-playbooks working either without using it with its absolute path! 
I'd change the recommended docs for osx to install through brew instead of pip

Comment: You should post this last comment as an answer if it indeed is the answer that solved the quesiton

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After installing ansible with `python3 -m pip install --user ansible`, I searched for the ansible binary and found it to be downloaded into `~/Library/Python/3.8/bin`. The simplest way is to figure this out is:

```
$ cd ~
$ find . | grep ansible
<lines omitted>
./Library/Python/3.8/bin/ansible
<lines omitted>
```

From there, its pretty easy, just update your .bash_profile or .zshrc with

```
export PATH="/path/to/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

And you should be good to go:

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/dbove/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
```

Answer (score 27):

`brew install ansible`
`brew link ansible`

Comment: I kept running into same issue over and over again when I used pip3 to install ansible. Finally, brew install ansible did the trick.

Comment: It may not be a direct answer to the question, but it did solve the underlying problem. Installing with pip just didn't work for me, albeit with --user or as sudo. With brew all was fine in one go.
`brew install ansible` was enough. No link needed.

Comment: i should add: first uninstall ansible:  python -m pip uninstall ansible then run brew install ansible, then brew link ansible. best way

Answer (score 6):

**Below commands worked for me:**

Uninstall ansible

> sudo pip uninstall ansible

Then install by using (Note: -H flag is important here which sets HOME variable to target user's home dir)

> **sudo -H pip3 install ansible**

Check the version by using

> ansible --version

Answer (score 5):

after installing like:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ansible
```

edit .zshrc:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

You shoud add `$HOME/.local/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall ansible `sudo pip uninstall ansible`.
Then install by using pip3 `sudo pip3 install ansible`.
Check the version by using `ansible --version`.

> ansible 2.10.3

**Note**: Make sure you have pip3 installed, In case you don't have then install by using `brew install python3`

Comment: I did exactly what you said but i still got ```zsh: command not found: ansible```

Comment: Use this below command which worked for me. Even I was facing the similar issue before.

>  **sudo -H pip3 install ansible**

Comment: @crg you must have installed ansible before with something else, uninstall that with that installer and then follow the steps. For example, You might have installed ansible before with apt-get, so uninstall that by using apt-get or whatever you have used before.

Comment: I finally did  `brew ansible` now it works thanks

Comment: yes if you are using homebrew then use brew for all packages that it supports for better compatibility

Comment: The full command for installing with Homebrew is `brew install ansible`

Answer (score 1):

i was seeing same error, i was missing ansible-lint

```
brew install ansible
brew install ansible-lint
```

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple ansible instances . I followed the steps below and rectified the ansible command not found error.

1. Uninstall old /all instances of ansible

```
python3 -m pip uninstall ansible
python3 -m pip uninstall ansible-core
```

2. Find all instances of ansible

```
cd ~
find . | grep ansible
```

3. Remove all directories from step 2

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible*
rm -rf /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
rm -rf ./.ansible
rm -rf ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_test
```

4. Install ansible once again

```
sudo yum install python3-pip 
pip3 install ansible
pip3 install openshift
```

5. Validate

```
pip3 list  | grep ansible
ansible (4.8.0)
ansible-core (2.11.6)
```

```
ansible --version
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.8 (default, Sep 12 2021, 04:40:35) [GCC 
8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]. This feature will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False 
in ansible.cfg.
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Sep 12 2021, 04:40:35) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

[ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible)